# Visual Studio Apache Cordova App project execute "save" extremely slow

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I'm starting to work with Phonegap and I've installed Visual Studio with Apache Cordova Tools.

I can create new Cordova project and change the project files. I can save the files it works well untill I run the project in debugger. After I stop the debugger and edit the project files every save takes about a minute - extremely slow.

I've downloaded an excample project form Microsoft site and I see the same problem with files save.

Does anybody familiar with the problem? Maybe I have to chang something in the Visual Studio configuration?

Comment: Is it a TypeScript or JavaScript project? if TypeScript, do you have Compile on Save on(off by default, you can look in project properties page)?
Also, are you debugging Ripple? For Ripple, there's an auto refresh on save. Can you try with a different target?
Are you using VS2013 or VS2015?

Comment: I've found the problem - There were too much Chrome tabs open.

Comment: Why did many Chrome tabs cause the save to take so long? Were you running out of memory?

Comment: In my case, VS first blocks for cca 20 seconds, ad then it hits a couple of JavaScript breakpoints at the end of each JS file as VS edbugger reloads them:: Jquery, cordova.js platformsovverrids.js. Pretty useles...

Comment: I dont think the chrome tabs thing is whats causing mine, as i still have d problems without chrome open. And is there a reason why VS is hitting breakpoints at the end of every js file, just like @matra stated

Comment: It's not just saving that is slow for me. I get input lag on all code files while I have a cordova project in the solution. Even when i'm not debugging and editing files that aren't in the cordova project. It's very frustrating. I have tried disabling the ripple refresh on save and it has made no difference. The only way to get it back to normal speed is to remove the project from the solution while I work on the other projects.

Comment: If you are still experiencing input lags like @DeanNorth mentioned or slow saving when using Cordova tools, help us investigate these issues further my emailing vscordovatools@microsoft.com.  We would like to get more details which will be easier to gather through email exchange.  Hitting breakpoints at the end of each JS file is a known issue that has been fixed in VS 2015 CTP6.

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off ripple. That seemed to help me

[image]